# Potential difference across the same wire

Tags: esp32, voltage

This issue may be weird, and I'm not sure if this is because of my wiring, but it would seem that **I do not have the same voltage** (or approximately the same voltage) between the **VCC(3.3V)** and the **VCC power rail** of my breadboard.

When measuring the voltage, there is **~0.300 mV** difference. And indeed measuring VCC and GND gives me **2.9 V**, instead of **3.3 V**

- I measured the flat jumper, it **doesn't have any resistance** (~~0)
- The ESP is consuming **below 100mA**, so no voltage drop

Could anyone explain me that ?
See attached pictures

[image: pin layout]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not "same" wire. There are at least contacts between board pin and bread board and bread board to wire... But if those rails are unloaded, it'll be quite unexpected to have any voltage drop

Comment: You are not measuring the wire. Try putting one probe on the actual wire where it goes into the breadboard, not the Arduino 3.3V point, and the other probe on the other end of that wire.

Comment: This question seem to belong in electrical engineering community rather than here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reasonable explanation is that the path between the 3.3V pin and the wire you are measuring does indeed have non-zero resistance. The wires look dirty to me from the photo, plus there would be internal resistance in the breadboard connectors.

You are measuring from the 3.3V pin and not the other end of the wire. I suggest using a different wire, or cleaning that one with sandpaper or by filing it down until you see shiny copper. Also try a different pin on the breadboard.

This is really a hardware or measurement issue. There is no way that a wire with zero resistance from one end to the other is going to have a 0.242V drop across it.

Comment: I struggled a few days to get it work, but it would seem that I don't have any more voltage drop :) (or below 10mv), thank you for your answer !